# How to make FAB like Google Calendar app?

Tags: android, android-animation, floating-action-button

How to make that type of FAB in the Google Calendar android app, which when you tap on it changes icon with a spinning animation + 2 more smaller icons zoom in on top of it + dismiss when you click anywhere else + add a layer of haze on the whole view?

Comment: check out this library https://github.com/futuresimple/android-floating-action-button

Comment: @Louis did you find the way to implement it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use some libraries than reinventing the wheel. Include this gradle dependency in your project

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.Karumi:ExpandableSelector:1.1.0'
}
```

And then create a FAB that is not but almost similar in function to GCallender's FAB.

Here is the full documentation : https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1987#!description

Comment: is it possible to do it without any libraries ?